# Django: Validation of parsed uploaded txt

Tags: python, django, validation

I have a model C which includes a field 'hash' which requires validation before saving.

```
# model.py
    class C(BaseModel):
        hash = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True,
               validators=[RegexValidator(regex='^.{10}$', 
               message='Length has to be 10', code='nomatch')])
        def clean(self):
            if self.hash is not None:
                if len(self.hash) != 10:
                    raise ValidationError({'hash': 'OMG'})
```

Now in signal.py, I call a function to extract information from a txt file and want to save the validated data into the database from the backend. However, the problem arises, when I call the save function from signal.py. If I don't add manual validation in extract_info.py, the clean function from model.py will not be raised, i.e. even if the hash is 'ddd', whose length is not 10, the hash will still be saved to the database from backend. If I add manual validation in extract_info.py as shown in the code below, or I call the clean function manually, something like data.clean(), the validation will be raised but however turn to the debug page, instead of showing error message at the top of the page, as it will happen if I manually put 'ddd' in the hash field from frontend and click save.

So, does anyone know if it is possible in django to parse data into the database from the backend, but still to raise the validation similar to when a user inputs data from the frontend, instead of showing the debug page?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
# signal.py
    @receiver(pre_save, sender=FileUpload)
    def parse_imaging_log(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        if instance.collection is not None:
            if '.txt' in instance.attach_file.name:
                l = extract_info(instance)  

# extract_info.py
    def extract_info(self):
        data= C(id=self.C.hash)
        if self.C.hash is not None or len(self.C.hash) == 10:
            data.save()
        else:
            raise ValidationError({'hash': 'OMG!!!!')
```